# Django-Weasyprint image not rendered

Tags: python, html, css, django, weasyprint

I have used Weasyprint to render my HTML file into a PDF. However,the image is not being displayed. I tried the solution for a similar problem posted here and rewrote my code as so:

```
response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s.pdf' % emp_id
pdf_doc = HTML(string=render_output,base_url=request.build_absolute_uri()).render()
pdf_doc.write_pdf(response)
return response
```

I have define the img tag in my template like below:

```
<img class="logo" src="static/app/nineleaps.png" alt="Not Found">
```

The PDF does not display the image and displays "Not Found" instead of it.
Is there a solution to this? Other html to pdf converters don't render my template as accurately as this, so I would prefer something that uses WeasyPrint only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want that `base_url` to be

```
request.build_absolute_uri('/')
```

– if you elide the location, you get the current request's absolute path, which is probably not something you can append `/static/app/nineleaps.png` to.

If that fails, you should be able to look at your `runserver`'s console output. The request Weasyprint attempts to make (and which 404s) should be visible there...

Comment: Solved my problem too.